# Strange behaviour printf - c lang

Tags: c

I was recently trying to make a program to escape escape sequences in a string. Everything looks fine and there are no error messages yet when I test the program, nothing prints.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

void escape(char s[], char t[]);

int main () {
 char s[MAXLINE], t[MAXLINE];
 int i, c;
 for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
     c = s[i];
  s[i] = '\0';
  escape(s, t);
  printf("%s\n",t);
  return 0;
}

void escape(char s[], char t[]) {
  int j = 0, i;
  for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    switch (s[i]) {
      case '\n':
       t[j] = '\\';
        t[++j] = 'n';
        ++j;
        break;
      case '\t':
        t[j] = '\\';
        t[++j] = 't';
        ++j;
        break;
      default:
        t[j] = s[i];
        ++j;
        break;
    }
  }
  t[j] = '\0';
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does this intend to do:  `for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
     c = s[i];` ? and could you provide us with an example input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop in the `main` function should be:

```
for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++)
    s[i] = c;
```

Comment: Welp, thanks for the quick reply, and sorry for wasting your time, that was an extremely stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are using

```
 c = s[i];
```

instead of

```
 s[i] = c;
```

in the for loop. Hence, `s` never gets initialized.